# Matrix Partial Derivative

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

For this formula: 
$F(W, H) = \frac{1}{2}\lVert V-WH \rVert^2$

I calculated the partial derivative using matrix calculus equations in the image:

$\bigtriangledown_HF(W,H) = -(V-WH)W^T=(WH-V)W^T $

$\bigtriangledown_WF(W,H) = -(V-WH)H = (WH-V)H$

But the book give the below result:

$\bigtriangledown_HF(W,H) = W^T(WH-V)$

$\bigtriangledown_WF(W,H) =  (WH-V)H^T$

could you explain:

why my answer is different from result of the book, and how to do it correctly. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just write it out:

$$ F(W,H) = \frac{1}{2} ||V-WH||^2 = \frac{1}{2} (V-WH)^T(V-WH) = $$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \left(V^TV -V^TWH -H^TW^TV + H^T W^T WH\right) $$

Now hit it with the derivative:
$$ F_H =  \frac{1}{2} \left(0 -W^TV - W^TV + \underbrace{( W^T WH + W^T W H)}_{product rule} \right ) = W^T( WH - V)$$

2nd One:

$$F_W = \frac{1}{2} \left(0 -V \partial_W( HW) - V \partial_W(W^TH^T) + \underbrace{( WH \partial_W ( H^TW^T) + WH \partial_W( HW)}_{product rule} \right ) = ( WH - V)H^T$$

Comment: Yes, thanks for you great explaination. I do the second one the same way, but encounter the problem: $\bigtriangledown_W(WH)$, there is no rules to apply. Could you please explain more?

Comment: chain rule is what you use!

Comment: Isn't the chain rule for matrix derivative left-multiplication? That is: $\bigtriangledown_W (V^TWH) = \frac{\partial W^T}{\partial W}\frac{\partial WH}{\partial W^T} \frac{\partial V^TWH}{\partial WH} = \partial _W(HW)V = HV$

Answer (score 1):

Functions like $F=\|M\|^2_F$ can be expressed in terms of the Frobenius product as $F=M:M$. Then it's a simple matter to find the differential and derivative
$$\eqalign{
 dF &= 2M:dM \cr
 \frac {\partial F} {\partial M} &= 2M \cr
} $$
Applying this to your particular function
$$\eqalign{
 dF &= (V-WH):d(V-WH) \cr
    &= -(V-WH):d(WH) \cr
    &= (WH-V):(dWH+WdH) \cr
    &= (WH-V):dWH + (WH-V):WdH \cr
    &= (WH-V)H^T:dW + W^T(WH-V):dH \cr
} $$
in the last line I've applied the rules for rearranging Frobenius products
$$\eqalign{
 A:BC &= B^TA:C \cr
 X:YZ &= XZ^T:Y \cr
} $$
Holding $H$ constant is equivalent to setting $dH=0$, and yields the differential/derivative with respect to $W$ 
$$\eqalign{
 dF &= (WH-V)H^T : dW \cr
 \frac {\partial F} {\partial W} &= (WH-V)H^T \cr
} $$
Similarly, setting $dW=0$ yields the derivative with respect to $H$.