# Partial derivative of matrix and vector

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Now assume $ M $ is a matrix and $x, y$ are vectors with different size.

And I have a function
$$
f(x, y) = \frac{1}{2}||M - xy^\top||^2_F
$$
What will be the first order derivative with respect to $x$ and $y$ separately?

And what if $x, y$ are matrices?

My thought is 
$\nabla f_x = (M-xy^\top)y$ and $\nabla f_y = x(M-xy^\top)$.

Is these correct?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ need to be the same size for the dot product to be defined.


Also, is $\|\cdot\|_F$ the operator norm?

Comment: It's $xy^\top$, not $x^\top y$. So I don't think they need to be the same size.  $||\cdot||_F$ is the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: When in doubt, express the function in terms of the components of the vectors.

Comment: There is general derivative formula that I believe uses the hetian or jacobian but can't seem to track it down. I came across it in a undergrad text book titled vector analysis. Think the cover had an old 1700 era painting of benjimin franklin or perhaps keplar or somebody if anyone knows what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

When I refer to another post, [Matrix Partial Derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765275/matrix-partial-derivative#765335).

The result should be 
$$\nabla f_x = (xy^\top-M)y$$ and $$\nabla f_y = x^\top(xy^\top-M)$$.

But I still have the question:
consider both $x$ and $y$ are the column vector, then the partial derivative of $x$ is a column, while the partial derivative of $y$ is a row vector. Could any one explain why?

Comment: An excellent question. The answer is that your result for $\nabla f_y$ needs to be transposed.

Comment: Yes, I think so. But can you explain why it need to be transposed?  I followed the calculation on another post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765275/matrix-partial-derivative

Comment: If you look at that post closely, you'll see that the function there is in terms of $(V-WH)$ not $(V-WH^T)$. Thus the need for transposing your result.